# replace value and divide it with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My origin data:

```
      Main_Genre    Genre_2  ... worldwide_gross  year
    0     Action  Adventure  ...    $700,059,566  2018
    1     Action  Adventure  ...    $678,815,482  2018
    2  Animation     Action  ...    $608,581,744  2018
    3     Action  Adventure  ...    $416,769,345  2018
    4     Action     Comedy  ...    $318,491,426  2018
```

I change `worldwide_gross` Dtype:

```
data2["worldwide_gross"]=data2[`"`worldwide_gross"].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
```

When I do this, the string doesn't convert to float.

```
.str.replace(',', '.')
```

New Data:

```
     Main_Genre  imdb_rating  length  worldwide_gross
    0     Action          7.4     135     7.000596e+25
    1     Action          8.5     156     6.788155e+25
    2  Animation          7.8     118     6.085817e+25
    3     Action          6.2     129     4.167693e+25
    4     Action          7.8     119     3.184914e+25
```

I want to remove the `e+` part and I want to show it as `700059566` or `700.059.566`.

I've tried and is not working

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format<br>pd.reset_option('display.float_format'`enter code here`)

lambda x: x*10 or 100 or 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try -

```
df['worldwide_gross'] = df['worldwide_gross'].str.replace('\$|\,','').astype(float)
df
  Main_Genre    Genre_2  ...   worldwide_gross  year
0     Action  Adventure  ...       700059566.0  2018
1     Action  Adventure  ...       678815482.0  2018
2  Animation     Action  ...       608581744.0  2018
3     Action  Adventure  ...       416769345.0  2018
4     Action     Comedy  ...       318491426.0  2018
```

Comment: FYI, you can combine those replace methods using a regex expression.  `df['worldwide_gross'].str.replace('\$|\,', '')`

Comment: Thank you for the comment Sir. Have updated the answer as per your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine for me. To divide by millions you can divide directly:

`data2["worldwide_gross"] = data2["worldwide_gross"] / 1000000`

Your change of display format seems fine for me.

For this small example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"worldwide_gross": ["$700,059,566", "$678,815,482"], "year": [2018, 2017]})
df["worldwide_gross"]=df["worldwide_gross"].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
pd.options.display.float_format = '{{0:.0f}}'.format
print(df)
```

the output is:

```
  worldwide_gross  year
0        700059566  2018
1        678815482  2017
```

Comment: my english is bad so i can't tell you exactly what i want to do 
I want to show it this way  700.059.566 but not ı could not

Comment: Please clarify. All you want is instead of commas to show dots? aka "$318,491,426" -> "318.491.426"? for that you can just replace "," with "."

Comment: . When I put it, string is not converted to float

Comment: You want it to be float, but when printing it should look like "111.111.111"? when the real number is "111111111"? I'm trying to understand, but it's a bit hard for me to understand to exactly do you want

Comment: I want to remove the +e I want to say, it is not important for me to have a dot between them. $700,059,566 to 700059566  or 700.059.566   like

Comment: then just use `pd.options.display.float_format = '{0:.0f}}'.format`. It works for me

Comment: It works for me. Format `{0:.0f}}` suppose to show float without commas and without exponent. What is the problem? is there still an exponent? a comma?

Comment: I use spyder and changed it manually and it got better, Thanks. Probably a problem with spyder